# opencv - closing a given contour (ellipse)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

im looking for a fast approach, to close an ellipse like the one on this image (this is my result after using cv::Range and cv::findNonZero. The circle moves, changes position and angle. So i cant use any static information to get the the bounding rect or something what could help). Did search for similar problems but the closest i could get was cv::approxpolydp, unfortunately this only works when i know some values, like size.

is there any mathematical approach to "close"(approximate ?) such a shape ? . I need this, as im using  cv::pointPolygonTest to check if a given point is inside the ellipse.

Thank you

Original
[image]

The Result i would like to get:
[image]

Comment: post original image.

Comment: unfortunately i cant post the original. Its an image with a lot going on in the background, thats why the ellipse is not always closed.

Comment: [This](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d73/samples_2cpp_2fitellipse_8cpp-example.html) might be useful.

Comment: try cv::fitEllipse followed by drawEllipse

Comment: "Its an image with a lot going on in the background": this is no reason to be unable to post it.

Answer (score 1):

If the shape is truly an ellipse, you can retrieve its equation by solving the 5x6 system of equations

```
 a X² + b XY + c Y² + d X + e Y + f = 0
```

where `X`, `Y` are taken from five distinct points of the curve.

For better accuracy (if needed) you can take more points and use least-squares fitting or robust least-squares fitting, but this is more complicated.

Then you'll need a little of analytical geometry to deduce the center, axis lengths and angles. It is also possible to design a Bresenham-like algorithm for direct drawing on the raster image.

Comment: this sounds good so far, could you give me a simple example using some random points, so that i can see how i need to proceed using your given equation  ?

Comment: sry i didnt mean that you should program for me, i just dont get how i need to interpret a, b, c,d,e,f in your equation .